# Firestore Querying Collection with Angular Dart

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular-dart

I am currently importing the following package:

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;
```

and then after initialising the firebase object fb, I initialise the firestore class:

```
var firestore = fb.firestore();
```

I would like to query and then iterate through my collection, showing each document's data, but don't quite now how, this is what I have so far

```
var doc = firestore.collection('data').doc('one').get()
```

This will return a future with DocumentSnapshot.

I see some older posts with different versions of angular-dart, but the wrapper code has changed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = firestore.collections('data').doc('one').get();
doc.then((d) {
  print(d.data());
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data